# in C++ with Argument Random Search how should I re adjust weights based on the amount of variation that they have?

Tags: c++, math

So I am programming in C++. I am making a class for Argument Random Search. So what I want is to be able to apply more training at the beginning and apply less when it is getting better at the job. I do have a type of implementation The thing is it uses a couple of digital low pass filters. The thing is when it starts the rewards will take a while to catch up. this is the enter rewards routine:

```
static LowPassFilter lpf1(dtUsed, 2 * M_PI * cutoffFrequeny);
static LowPassFilter lpf2(dtUsed, 2 * M_PI * cutoffFrequeny);
static double abv;
double avg = lpf1.update(rew);
if (rew > avg) abv = lpf2.update(rew);
double rel = 1;
if (avg > .00000001) rel = (abv - avg) / avg;
rewards[rewNum++] = rel * rew;
if (rewNum > 15)
```

rew is the input. I really do not know how these filters work. I just downloaded them from Github.

Actually I should adjust the learning rate, but I still have the problem of having to wait for the filters to catch up.

Answer (score -1):

What I actually thought of is taking the result and dividing it by a filter with an input of the constant of 1.0